# Drop Select with Ajax not working in Jquery 1.8.3 . Worked well with 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, html-select, jquery-1.4, jquery-1.8

I am using the following with JQuery 1.4.2 and it is working fine.
However if i use Jquery 1.8.3 this stop working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.time-location').change(function(){
     var from = $('.time-location').val();
     var dataString = "&from=" + from;
         $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "loadajax.php",
           data: dataString,
           success : function(data){
             $('.world-time').show();
             $('.world-time').html(data);
           }
         });
    });
});    
<div id="time-location-box">
   <div class="world-time" id="world-time" >
      <?php include('loadajax.php');?>
    </div>      
    <div id="time-location-sel-box">
       <select class="time-location" name="time-location" id="time-location">
            <option value="America/New_York">Washington DC,US(EST</option>
        <option value="America/New_York">NewYork, US(EST)</option>
        <option value="America/Chicago">Chicago, US(CST)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried to change the success : function to done : function as it seems to be deprecated but it didn't helped.

Comment: try changing the .change(function() to .on('change',function(), this kind of stuff is handled by .on() now